# I am getting runtime Null Point Exception In my Android App

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments

I am getting runtime Null Point Exception In my Android App.

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method  'com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListenercom.google.firebase.database.Query.addChildEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener)' on a null object reference

Here is  my Firebase connection:

```
package com.example.nagesh.newapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class Last extends AppCompatActivity {


private ListView lst;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_last);
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://newapp-46492.firebaseio.com/Users");

    init();


}

private void init() {

    lst = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstv);

    FirebaseListAdapter<String> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(this, String.class, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, databaseReference) {

        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, String model, int position) {

            TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            textView.setText(model);
        }

    };

    lst.setAdapter(firebaseListAdapter);

}

}
```

I am beginner....Help me.

Comment: Where in your code is the ChildEventListener? Please share more code.

Answer (score 0):

your Reference like below.

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().child("Users");
```

its directly gives a reference of  `"https://newapp-46492.firebaseio.com"`